# Can't read Protege ontology in Jena

Tags: jena, protege

I'm new to onotlogy and Java. I learn it now and have some theoretical knowledge.
I use "apache-jena-3.1.0" in Eclipse and Protege editor 5.0.0 beta 23.

First of all, I created a simple ontology in Jena. Something like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);
...
OntClass gen1 = m.createClass(st + "Generation_1");
OntClass gen2 = m.createClass(st + "Generation_2");
...
ObjectProperty hasParent = m.createObjectProperty(st + "hasParent");
...
m.write(System.out);

try {
m.write(new FileWriter("C:/java/family1_RDF.owl"), "RDF/XML");
m.write(new FileWriter ("C:/java/family2_N3.owl"), "N3");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It works well. I'm able to read saved ontology in my application and to open it in Protege editor.

Then I created simple ontology in Protege. Saved it in RDF/XML Syntax.
I tried to open it in my application by the code:

```
OntModel base = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM_RDFS_INF);
    try {
        base.read(new FileReader ("C:/java/asutp_class.owl"), "OWL/XML");
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    base.write(System.out);
```

It didn't work. Eclipse sent me a lot of mistakes:

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: [line: 271, col: 120] {E210} Encoding error with non-ascii characters.
    at org.apache.jena.riot.system.ErrorHandlerFactory$ErrorHandlerStd.error(ErrorHandlerFactory.java:128)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangRDFXML$ErrorHandlerBridge.error(LangRDFXML.java:246)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.impl.ARPSaxErrorHandler.error(ARPSaxErrorHandler.java:37)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.impl.XMLHandler.warning(XMLHandler.java:196)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.impl.XMLHandler.warning(XMLHandler.java:173)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.impl.XMLHandler.warning(XMLHandler.java:168)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.impl.ParserSupport.warning(ParserSupport.java:207)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.impl.ParserSupport.checkEncoding(ParserSupport.java:192)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.impl.URIReference.resolve(URIReference.java:167)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.states.WantDescription.startElement(WantDescription.java:63)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.impl.XMLHandler.startElement(XMLHandler.java:111)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNamespaceBinder.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNamespaceBinder.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.impl.RDFXMLParser.parse(RDFXMLParser.java:150)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.impl.RDFXMLParser.parse(RDFXMLParser.java:134)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.ARP.load(ARP.java:99)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangRDFXML.parse(LangRDFXML.java:140)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParserRegistry$ReaderRIOTLang.read(RDFParserRegistry.java:187)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.process(RDFDataMgr.java:873)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:288)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:273)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.adapters.RDFReaderRIOT.read(RDFReaderRIOT.java:62)
    at org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.read(ModelCom.java:245)
    at org.apache.jena.ontology.impl.OntModelImpl.read(OntModelImpl.java:2117)
    at asutp_lassification.main(asutp_lassification.java:14)

What the problem is? How can I open Protege's ontology in my Jena application?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried out different "OntModelSpec"

Comment: I doubt that Jena can read things in the OWL/XML format.  You'll need to save the ontology from Protege in an RDF serialization format like Turtle or RDF/XML.  That said, the trace *does* look like it's trying to read the XML.  The message says, "Encoding error with non-ascii characters."  Do you have non-ascii characters in there?

Comment: As I wrote - I tried to save in a RDF/XML format - the same problem. Looked for that characters, but didn't find. Shared it here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8XNVi6pdRrgLWhHT3p2aEdEaDQ

Comment: my mention of owl/xml is based on this part of your code:  `base.read(new FileReader ("C:/java/asutp_class.owl"), "OWL/XML");`. It's probably not the problem, but is anything different if you use rdf/xml there?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I experimented with different variants. Posted the last one. Nothing different with RDF/XML. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 271 has a URI with fragment with "#АСУ1" which when I look at the bytes are indeed not ASCII (they are  d0 90 d0 a1 d0 a3 in UTF-8 encoding).

RDF/XML is an old standard and requires URIs (strictly "RDF URI References" which means IRIs need encoding). Turtle is better at handling IRIs directly.

Comment: Thank you very much! The problem was in theese symbols. I thought about them and deleted individuals from the ontology by Protoge, but only moved them under the "Thing" class. It's ok now and works perfectly. I will think about Turtle.