# Problems to read a owl ontology using Jena

Tags: java, jena, owl, ontology

I'm trying to a read a owl ontology using [Jena](http://jena.apache.org/). The ontology was created in [Protégé](http://protege.stanford.edu/).

This is (part of) my original .owl file (some terms are in Portuguese):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


<!DOCTYPE Ontology [
    <!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
    <!ENTITY xml "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" >
    <!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
]>


<Ontology xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xml:base="http://james.miranda.br/Onto"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     ontologyIRI="http://james.miranda.br/Onto"
     versionIRI="http://james.miranda.br/Onto/1.0.0">
    <Prefix name="" IRI="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"/>
    <Prefix name="owl" IRI="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"/>
    <Prefix name="rdf" IRI="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"/>
    <Prefix name="xsd" IRI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"/>
    <Prefix name="rdfs" IRI="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"/>
    <Annotation>
        <AnnotationProperty abbreviatedIRI="rdfs:comment"/>
        <Literal xml:lang="en" datatypeIRI="&rdf;PlainLiteral">Ontology for the decision process</Literal>
    </Annotation>
    <Annotation>
        <AnnotationProperty abbreviatedIRI="rdfs:comment"/>
        <Literal xml:lang="pt" datatypeIRI="&rdf;PlainLiteral">Ontologia para o processo de tomada de decisões.</Literal>
    </Annotation>
    <Declaration>
        <Class IRI="#AcaoDesign"/>
    </Declaration>
    <Declaration>
        <Class IRI="#Alternativa"/>
    </Declaration>
```

Complete file in [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/c8VgxJc9)

This is my class:

```
public class ReadOntology {


    public static void run(String ontologyInFile) {

        OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM_RULE_INF, null);
        InputStream ontologyIn = FileManager.get().open(ontologyInFile);

        loadModel(model, ontologyIn);
    }


    /** 
     * @param m
     * @param ontologyIn */
    protected static void loadModel(OntModel m, InputStream ontologyIn) {
        try {
             m.read(ontologyIn, "RDF/XML");
             //also tried m.read(ontologyIn, "OWL/XML");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

I'm using this class in my HTTP Servlet class like below:

```
ServletContext context = this.getServletContext();
String fullPath = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/ontology/Onto.owl");
ReadOntology.run(fullPath);
```

and I was receiving the following error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.jena.riot.system.stream.JenaIOEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Error [line: 27, col: 64] {E201} Multiple children of property element
```

I was thinking that the problem was log4j, but the comments in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947143/configure-log4j-with-glassfish-and-netbeans-to-use-jena) took me to another direction.

With a bit of research and attention, I saw in the [Ontology API documentation](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/) that Jena does not have full support to OWL2, and apparently, this was the problem. The answer for [this another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288133/is-ontology-file-created-in-protege-with-rdf-xml-format-a-rdf-file-or-the-owl-fi) indicated that the solution could be in the .owl file.

Finally, I saved it in RDF/XML (the file extension is still .owl) and the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
    <!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
    <!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
]>


<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xml:base="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
    <Ontology rdf:about="http://james.miranda.br/Onto">
        <rdfs:comment xml:lang="en">Ontology for the decision making process</rdfs:comment>
        <rdfs:comment xml:lang="pt">Ontologia para o processo de tomada de decisões.</rdfs:comment>
        <versionIRI rdf:resource="http://james.miranda.br/Onto/1.0.0"/>
    </Ontology>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Object Properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://james.miranda.br/Onto#atende -->

    <ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://james.miranda.br/Onto#atende">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;InverseFunctionalProperty"/>
    </ObjectProperty>



    <!-- http://james.miranda.br/Onto#compoe -->

    <ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://james.miranda.br/Onto#compoe">
        <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="http://james.miranda.br/Onto#ehParteDe"/>
    </ObjectProperty>



    <!-- http://james.miranda.br/Onto#conflitaCom -->

    <ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://james.miranda.br/Onto#conflitaCom">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;ReflexiveProperty"/>
    </ObjectProperty>
```

Complete file in [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/cxdv5Tp8).

but the same error persists. I found [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30767502/loading-owl-file-with-jena) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38254356/cant-read-protege-ontology-in-jena) with similar problem, but the solutions did not help me.

I don't know what to do now. What I'm doing wrong?

**Information:**

- Ubuntu 14.04;
- JDK 1.8.0;
- Netbeans 8.0.2;
- GlassFish 4.1;
- Jena 3.1.0;

Comment: Hi, without getting access to the whole ontology, no way to help. Can you share it somehow? Your code looks ok. And I don't think that Jena will have problems in parsing the ontology, even if there are some OWL2 constructs contained in it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @AKSW. I put two links for PasteBin with the whole ontology.

Comment: Thanks. For me loading the ontology works perfectly when I run it within my IDE with Maven dependencies for Apache Jena 3.1.0. (`model.size()` = 1376 triples) . So something else must go wrong. Especially the line number of your error message just contains a bunch of `/` characters for comments, thus, nothing would be parsed here for OWL. Can you run it via a separate main method within your Java project?

Comment: I created the whole project again from the beginning and now it's working, even without any changes in my class. I can't understand it, but thanks for your help anyway, @AKSW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to inform anyone with a similar problem than mine (or anyone that wants to read a protégé ontology using Jena), below is the process and code that I used to achieve it:

1 - In Protégé, save your file as RDF/XML;

2 - Copy the file to your WEB-INF directory (under any sub-directory if you want);

3 - Create a class to read your ontology. For example:

```
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import org.apache.jena.ontology.*;
 import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
 import org.apache.jena.util.FileManager;

 public class ReadOntology {

    public OntModel model;

    public static void run(String ontologyInFile) {

        model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM_RULE_INF, null);
        InputStream ontologyIn = FileManager.get().open(ontologyInFile);

        loadModel(model, ontologyIn);
    }


    /** 
     * @param m
     * @param ontologyIn */
    protected static void loadModel(OntModel m, InputStream ontologyIn) {
        try {
             m.read(ontologyIn, "RDF/XML");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

4 - Using a Servlet class (that extends HttpServlet), you can use the created class like below:

```
ServletContext context = this.getServletContext();
String fullPath = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/yourOntologyName.owl");
ReadOntology.run(fullPath);
ExtendedIterator<OntClass> classIterator = ReadOntology.model.listClasses(); 
while (classIterator.hasNext()) { 
    OntClass ontClass = classIterator.next(); 
    System.out.println(ontClass.toString());
}
```